# Explanation of two boolean variables being both true or both false

Tags: java, boolean-logic

I was asked in a tutorial to write an expression a follows:

Given boolean variables:

```
boolean a, b;
```

write an expression that is `true` if *either* `a` and `b` are both `true` *or* if `a` and `b` are both `false`.

The answer I got from quiz was:

```
a && b || !a && !b
```

Please explain what that means.

Comment: Please show what you understand about it yourself first

Comment: If you can't tell us what you're struggling with, then we can't really help you any better than your average tutorial can. So either google for one or explain what parts you do and don't understand.

Comment: Specifically, what if you literally wrote `a==true && b==true`? Do you understand that much?

Comment: Why not `a == b`?

Comment: Or  why not `!(a^b)`

Comment: @OneCricketeer "Or why not" because that's far more obscure than using equality :) I find that `^` with booleans is far more readably written as `!=` anyway (it "scares" people less).

Comment: Do you want to understand what those symbols mean? Do you wanna know what is the order in which the operations are executed? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take this piece by piece. I'm going to put paranthesis around things to make more sense.

`(a && b) || (!a && !b)`

First, start off with the `(a && b)`

With this, all this means is that `a == true AND(&&) b == true`
So, both `a` and `b` have to be true in this statement

Second, the `(!a && !b)`

Similar to the previous, all this means is that `a == false AND(&&) b == false`
So, both `a` and `b` have to be false in this statement

Now, put an `OR(||)` in between, and it means that either both have to be true, or both have to be false.

Answer (score 0):

```
a&&b    is only true when a is true and b is true.
```

a||b is true if one of (a,b) is true
Assume a = true and b = true, then !a = false,!b = false(negation).
In other words,the statement    !a&&!b    is true when both a and b are false, otherwise it is false.
So the statement    a&&b || !a&&!b    is true when a and b are both true(    a&&b    will be true) or when a and b is false(    !a&&!b     will be true)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the quiz has suggested a poor solution. The best answer is simply:

```
a == b
```

However, to explain the expression `a && b || !a && !b` you should know that when a boolean variable is part of a logical expression, its value become part of that expression. In other words, these two expressions are identical:

```
a
a == true
```

Similarly, these two expressions are identical:

```
!a
a == false
```

Also note that the logical operator `&&` takes precedence over (ie it is evaluated *before*) `||`.

Putting that all together, we can convert the expression

```
a && b || !a && !b
```

to the equivalent:

```
(a == true && b == true) || (a == false && b == false)
```

and then to English pseudocode:

```
(a is true AND b is true) OR (a is false AND b is false)
```